# Generate all possible sentences from "N" lists using Python

Tags: python

```
list_1 = ['happy','sad']
list_2 = ['dinner','lunch']
```

I need to generate all possible sentences.

```
required_output = [‘happy dinner’,’happy lunch’,’sad dinner’, ‘sad lunch’]
```

But I always don’t have only 2 lists. Sometimes I have 3,4,6,8 etc lists. I need help in generating all possible sentences dynamically in python. Thank you !!

Comment: But number of lists always change for each experiment

Comment: Do not change your question so drastically that the given answers become useless.

Comment: @AlokThakur, how will that give him all the combinations. It will only pair up the words with same indices. Also, list lengths may be different, `zip` wont work there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Multiple list cases You can do like this

**Try this:-**

```
import itertools
final_list = [list1,list2,list3,....]
print(list(itertools.product(*final_list))) #you will get all possible matches
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools
list_1 = ['happy','sad'] 
list_2 = ['dinner','lunch'] 
l = [list_1, list_2]
final_list = ["{} {}".format(*i) for i in itertools.product(*l, repeat = 2)]
```

Output:

```
['happy dinner', 'happy lunch', 'sad dinner', 'sad lunch']
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. experiment_1=[[‘happy', 'sad'], ['today', 'never']]

experiment_2=[[‘happy', 'sad'], ['today', 'never'], ['lunch', 'dinner', 'food’]]

experiment_3=[[‘happy', 'sad'], ['today', 'never'], ['lunch', 'dinner', 'food’],………….]

I have more than 60 experiments like this. With this itertools I need to modify code every time. Is it possible to do it dynamically?
Thank you

Comment: @kumar glad to help! Please see my recent edit. You can make all your smaller lists elements of a larger list and use unpacking.

Comment: That helped. But I need to manually type {} depending on length of the experiment list. Is there any way to dynamically type {} instead of manually? Thanks.

Comment: @kumar how are you getting your data? Are you reading from a file?

Comment: am reading from a text file. I have words written in a text file for all experiments.                                                                                              
with open("few_lines.txt","r") as infile:
    lines=infile.readlines()
words_list=[]
for i in range(len(lines)):
    words_list.append(list())
    for token in lines[i].split(', '):
        words_list[i].append(token)

Comment: If I can dynamically type { } "N" number of times  in your code based on experiement list length, i will get the required output.

Answer (score 0):

I may give an idea , lets say i have 4 lists that each contain words. Now, rather than combining it directly..we can first find all combinations of the lists. Combinations for 2-word sentences, 3-word.., and 4-word.

The set of all the index combination is in the `index_combin` list. This is also useful as your data.

Also, we will use this to get the 2, 3, and 4 combination a from the 4 lists. This is stored in `sets`.

**Here is the code:**

```
import itertools as it

list_1 = ['happy','sad'];
list_2 = ['dinner','lunch'];
list_3 = ['indoor', 'outdoor', 'restaurant'];
list_4 = ['alone', 'together'];
combined = [list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4];

index_combin = [];
words_combin = [];

for i in range(2,len(combined)+1):
    dummy = it.combinations(range(0, len(combined)),i);
    index_combin.append(list(dummy));

sets = [];
for i in index_combin:
    for j in i:
        sets.append([combined[k] for k in j]);

for i in sets:
    for j in list(it.product(*i)):
        print(j)
```

**Output:**

```
('happy', 'dinner')
('happy', 'lunch')
('sad', 'dinner')
('sad', 'lunch')
('happy', 'indoor')
('happy', 'outdoor')
('happy', 'restaurant')
('sad', 'indoor')
('sad', 'outdoor')
('sad', 'restaurant')
('happy', 'alone')
('happy', 'together')
('sad', 'alone')
('sad', 'together')
('dinner', 'indoor')
('dinner', 'outdoor')
('dinner', 'restaurant')
('lunch', 'indoor')
('lunch', 'outdoor')
('lunch', 'restaurant')
('dinner', 'alone')
('dinner', 'together')
('lunch', 'alone')
('lunch', 'together')
('indoor', 'alone')
('indoor', 'together')
('outdoor', 'alone')
('outdoor', 'together')
('restaurant', 'alone')
('restaurant', 'together')
('happy', 'dinner', 'indoor')
('happy', 'dinner', 'outdoor')
('happy', 'dinner', 'restaurant')
('happy', 'lunch', 'indoor')
('happy', 'lunch', 'outdoor')
('happy', 'lunch', 'restaurant')
('sad', 'dinner', 'indoor')
('sad', 'dinner', 'outdoor')
('sad', 'dinner', 'restaurant')
('sad', 'lunch', 'indoor')
('sad', 'lunch', 'outdoor')
('sad', 'lunch', 'restaurant')
('happy', 'dinner', 'alone')
('happy', 'dinner', 'together')
('happy', 'lunch', 'alone')
('happy', 'lunch', 'together')
('sad', 'dinner', 'alone')
('sad', 'dinner', 'together')
('sad', 'lunch', 'alone')
('sad', 'lunch', 'together')
('happy', 'indoor', 'alone')
('happy', 'indoor', 'together')
('happy', 'outdoor', 'alone')
('happy', 'outdoor', 'together')
('happy', 'restaurant', 'alone')
('happy', 'restaurant', 'together')
('sad', 'indoor', 'alone')
('sad', 'indoor', 'together')
('sad', 'outdoor', 'alone')
('sad', 'outdoor', 'together')
('sad', 'restaurant', 'alone')
('sad', 'restaurant', 'together')
('dinner', 'indoor', 'alone')
('dinner', 'indoor', 'together')
('dinner', 'outdoor', 'alone')
('dinner', 'outdoor', 'together')
('dinner', 'restaurant', 'alone')
('dinner', 'restaurant', 'together')
('lunch', 'indoor', 'alone')
('lunch', 'indoor', 'together')
('lunch', 'outdoor', 'alone')
('lunch', 'outdoor', 'together')
('lunch', 'restaurant', 'alone')
('lunch', 'restaurant', 'together')
('happy', 'dinner', 'indoor', 'alone')
('happy', 'dinner', 'indoor', 'together')
('happy', 'dinner', 'outdoor', 'alone')
('happy', 'dinner', 'outdoor', 'together')
('happy', 'dinner', 'restaurant', 'alone')
('happy', 'dinner', 'restaurant', 'together')
('happy', 'lunch', 'indoor', 'alone')
('happy', 'lunch', 'indoor', 'together')
('happy', 'lunch', 'outdoor', 'alone')
('happy', 'lunch', 'outdoor', 'together')
('happy', 'lunch', 'restaurant', 'alone')
('happy', 'lunch', 'restaurant', 'together')
('sad', 'dinner', 'indoor', 'alone')
('sad', 'dinner', 'indoor', 'together')
('sad', 'dinner', 'outdoor', 'alone')
('sad', 'dinner', 'outdoor', 'together')
('sad', 'dinner', 'restaurant', 'alone')
('sad', 'dinner', 'restaurant', 'together')
('sad', 'lunch', 'indoor', 'alone')
('sad', 'lunch', 'indoor', 'together')
('sad', 'lunch', 'outdoor', 'alone')
('sad', 'lunch', 'outdoor', 'together')
('sad', 'lunch', 'restaurant', 'alone')
('sad', 'lunch', 'restaurant', 'together')
```

You can also permute each of these sets of words.